# Node.js. What is the proper way to make things run repeatedly?

Tags: node.js, parsing, memory-leaks, scope, closures

My goal is to make a simple JSON parser which runs continuously. 
As I imagined it - an infinity loop makes a request and stores data in my DB. Simple.
But there always were memory leaks.
What is the proper way to make things run repeatedly over and over again in Node.js? What is actually memory leak? Why and how is it happening? I have tried it to do with setInterval, setTimeOut, processNextTick, setImmediate, promises but there is always the same result! I am obviously something missing.

---

What I get now:

```
function getItems(callback) {
  request({
    url: 'http://foo.com',
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200 && body) {
      var total_count = body.total_count;
      var body = body.results_html;

      ...
      setTimeout(function() {callback(body}, 1000);
    }
  });
}

function series(item) {
  if (item) {
    getItems(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      return series(true);
    });
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

series(true);
```

Comment: From what I can tell. Nothing in the code above looks suspicious. I therefore suspect that the bit described as `...` is what's causing memory leak. To test this, try running the code above empty. That is, make the infinite request but completely comment out the `...` part and do nothing. That would prove where the memory leak really is.

Comment: Testing code without "..." with process.memoryUsage()). That is what I get: { rss: 42496000, heapTotal: 34693888, heapUsed: 18316464 }
{ rss: 43859968, heapTotal: 34693888, heapUsed: 20072120 }
{ rss: 44683264, heapTotal: 35725824, heapUsed: 20766784 }          ........{ rss: 86323200, heapTotal: 77269504, heapUsed: 53720512 }
{ rss: 87302144, heapTotal: 77269504, heapUsed: 54381096 }
Killed. Thank you for the reply.